# Loop over data frame columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `data frame` in pandas like below.

`df`

```
, pkg
1,test_1
2,test_2
3,test_3
```

I have a directory that has subdirectories for each `pkg` in local. Each `pkg` subdirectory has a file called `pkg.json`

```
C:\Users\viru\Desktop\Test\pkg\pkg.json
```

I want to open each `pkg.json` file and print the contents of the file in a loop.

The for loop is below

```
for package in df1:
 package = 'package'
 with open('C:\Users\viru\Desktop\Test\{}\{}.json'.format(package,package)) as data_file:
   data = json.load(data_file)
   print data
```

I have tried like above but getting error

```
No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\viru\\Desktop\\Test\\pkg\\pkg.json'
```

How can I achieve what I want

Comment: Apparently you have 2 usernames; `viru` and `d58426`. So the code appears to be looking in the wrong directories for the files.

Comment: @roganjosh please check edited Question

Comment: You say each `pkg` directory has a file pkg.json, but it's actually looking for that literally, do you mean instead to look for `..\\Test\\test_1\\test_1.json`, in that case you want to iterate over the elements of the pkg column, not over the columns of the data frame.

Comment: The error is saying the files don't exist. You've since edited out an unusual error that would have explained the issue just fine. The actual error could come from anything just as simple as the one you made writing the question; you'll probably need to debug this on your end.

Comment: @jxramos what you said is correct I want to iterate over elements of the package column But don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're mistakenly iterating over the columns, so to iterate over the elements of the `pkg` column you should try

```
for pkg in df['pkg'] :
   with open('C:\Users\viru\Desktop\Test\{}\{}.json'.format(pkg,pkg)) as data_file:
       data = json.load(data_file)
       print data
```